# Pandas: Pivoting on a df with 2 columns

Tags: pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe with two columns. The first column is a country name, the second column is the ID of an occurrence.

```
Country      Occurrence ID
   A              One
   B              Two
   C              One
   A             Three
   D              One
   D              One
  ...             ...
```

I want to pivot my dataframe such that I have an aggregate of all the occurrence ID's that happened in each country

```
Country        Occurrence One         Occurrence Two      Occurrence Three
  A                 5                      9                    13
  B                 6                      10                   15
  C                 7                      11                   19
```

I'm unfamiliar with how pivot, pivot_table or unstack work and haven't been able to work this one out using google. Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Use `df.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Occurrence ID', aggfunc='size')`

Comment: Thanks you very much!